# Prove the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{n}-(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{n-1} \geq-n$

Tags: inequality

I am talking about a generalization of this inequality posed [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002529/how-prove-this-x3y3z33-ge-2x2y2z2).

> let $x,y,z>0$ and such $xyz=1$, show that
>   $$x^3+y^3+z^3+3\ge 2(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

I am trying to prove the following inequality,

$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n(n-2)} x_i^{n}-(n-1)\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{n-1} \geq-n$$

where $x_i\in \mathbb{R^+}$ and  $\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n x_i=1$.

The methods used to solve the linked inequality doesn't seem to be applied in this general case. Can anyone help me in proving it?

Comment: How about $x_i=1$ for all $i$?

Comment: @Sayan: See the edit.

Comment: It seems mixing variable still helps us. But it is just to cumbersome to write. May be when I have loads of time in near future, I would write it down here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean the following inequality?

Let $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$ be positive numbers such that $x_1x_2...x_n=1$. Prove that:
$$(n-2)(x_1^n+x_2^n+...+x_n^n)-(n-1)\left(x_1^{n-1}+x_2^{n-1}+...+x_n^{n-1}\right)+n\geq0$$

Answer (score 1):

I wish to use lagrange multipliers:
$$f(x,y,z)=\sum x^n-(n-1)\sum x^{n-1}+n\\
g(x,y,z)=\prod x=1$$
Now:
$$nx^{n-1}-(n-1)^2x^{n-2}=\lambda(1/x)\implies \lambda=nx^n-(n-1)^2x^{n-1}$$
One such acceptable solution is $x=y=z=1$ where $f(x)=0$